# How to specify a custom column type in Prisma?

Tags: mysql, geometry, migration, geospatial, prisma

Prisma does [not support geospatial columns](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1798) yet. I need to add a mySQL `GEOMETRY` type column to my database. I can write a custom migration, but the whole point of Prisma is to manage my migrations.

How do I specify a custom column type in a Prisma schema file? Can be mySQL-specific.